# Number is equal to Variable?

Tags: actionscript-3

As seen in the following code (`var d = 8`), I'm defining the variable d as eight.  However,  I am not making 'eight' 'd', so why is this true: `8 === d`?

Edit:  This is simple math, however computer science and math aren't the same thing, and I should've read the ECMAScript syntax rules for `===`.  I apologize for asking such a dumb question here on SO.

Comment: The algorithm used for the `==` operation is defined at [ES5 #11.9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) (though AS3 in strict mode will thrown an error for comparison between unrelated types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because once you have assigned 8 to variable d 8 == d is the same as saying 8==8

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between `d == 8` and `8 == d`. They both evaluate the expressions `8` and `d`, and compare the resulting values. This is how practically all programming languages work.

You seem to be interpreting `X == Y` as testing *is X set to Y?*. That's not how comparison expressions work, since the operands can be arbitrary expressions. For instance, how would you explain something like `x + 10 == y - 30` using your interpration, since neither operand is a simple variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a variable called `d` and setting its value to eight. Because the value on the left is equal to the value on the right, the comparison is true. In JavaScript, == [compares values](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).